# Need to transfer Elements from the web to an arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator, switch-statement

After successfully scraping the web with the relevent data I need to transfer it to an `ArrayList`.

As you can see below I printed out the data. Now all I need to do is put it in an `ArrayList`. Any idea?

Code:

```
static String html = "http://games.espn.go.com/fba/playerrater?&slotCategoryId=1";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, InterruptedException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
    String title = doc.title();
   System.out.println(title);


    Iterator<Element> trSIter = doc.select("table.playerTableTable").iterator();
    while (trSIter.hasNext()) {
        Element  trEl = trSIter.next().child(0);
        Elements  tdEls = trEl.children();
        Iterator<Element> tdIter = tdEls.select("tr").iterator();
        boolean firstRow = true;
        while (tdIter.hasNext()) {

            Element tr = (Element)tdIter.next();
            if (firstRow) {
                firstRow = false;
                continue;
            }

        while (tdIter.hasNext()) 
        {  

            System.out.println("============================");
            Element tdEl = tdIter.next();
            String name = 
                    tdEl.getElementsByClass("playertablePlayerName").text();
            System.out.println("Name: "+name);
            String pointStr = 
                    tdEl.getElementsByClass("sortedCell").text();
            System.out.println("points: "+pointStr);
            //System.out.println(tdEl);
            Elements tdsEls = tdEl.select("td.playertableData");
            Iterator<Element> columnIt = tdsEls.iterator();
            boolean firstRow1 = true;


            while(columnIt.hasNext())
            {


                Element column = columnIt.next();
                 String stat1 =column.text();
                System.out.print(column.className()+":"+column.text()+",");
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name: Kobe Bryant, LAL SG
points: 14.68
playertableData:1,playertableData:0.62,playertableData:2.37,playertableData:1.36,playertableData:1.20,playertableData:2.66,playertableData:1.73,playertableData:0.15,playertableData:4.59,playertableData sortedCell:14.68,============================
Name: Joe Johnson, Atl SG, SF
points: 10.04
playertableData:2,playertableData:-0.58,playertableData:2.05,playertableData:3.27,playertableData:0.46,playertableData:1.41,playertableData:0.97,playertableData:0.01,playertableData:2.44,playertableData sortedCell:10.04,============================
Name: James Harden, OKC SG
points: 9.28
playertableData:3,playertableData:0.73,playertableData:2.48,playertableData:2.53,playertableData:0.53,playertableData:1.00,playertableData:0.46,playertableData:-0.25,playertableData:1.81,playertableData sortedCell:9.28,============================
Name: Andre Iguodala, Phi SF, SG
points: 8.74
playertableData:4,playertableData:0.42,playertableData:-1.47,playertableData:1.57,playertableData:1.31,playertableData:1.90,playertableData:3.13,playertableData:0.68,playertableData:1.19,playertableData sortedCell:8.74,============================
Name: Monta Ellis, GS PG, SG
points: 8.38
playertableData:5,playertableData:-0.58,playertableData:0.77,playertableData:1.15,playertableData:-0.14,playertableData:2.73,playertableData:2.11,playertableData:-0.12,playertableData:2.46,playertableData sortedCell:8.38,============================
Name: Kevin Martin, Hou SG
points: 7.87
playertableData:6,playertableData:-0.91,playertableData:3.01,playertableData:2.85,playertableData:0.02,playertableData:0.79,playertableData:0.46,playertableData:-0.66,playertableData:2.31,playertableData sortedCell:7.87,============================
Name: Jarrett Jack, Nor PG, SG
points: 7.67
playertableData:7,playertableData:0.15,playertableData:1.49,playertableData:0.51,playertableData:0.44,playertableData:3.25,playertableData:0.33,playertableData:-0.12,playertableData:1.62,playertableData sortedCell:7.67,============================
Name: Jason Terry, Dal SG
points: 7.31
playertableData:8,playertableData:-0.89,playertableData:0.77,playertableData:3.27,playertableData:-0.53,playertableData:1.41,playertableData:2.24,playertableData:-0.39,playertableData:1.42,playertableData sortedCell:7.31,============================
Name: Luke Ridnour, Min PG, SG
points: 6.21
playertableData:9,playertableData:1.05,playertableData:0.40,playertableData:1.57,playertableData:-0.37,playertableData:1.38,playertableData:1.22,playertableData:-0.12,playertableData:1.08,playertableData sortedCell:6.21,============================
Name: Ray Allen, Bos SG  DTD
points: 6.19
playertableData:10,playertableData:1.21,playertableData:1.35,playertableData:3.06,playertableData:-0.16,playertableData:0.31,playertableData:0.20,playertableData:-0.79,playertableData:1.01,playertableData sortedCell:6.19,============================
Name: Tyreke Evans, Sac PG, SG
points: 6.05
playertableData:11,playertableData:-1.04,playertableData:0.05,playertableData:0.19,playertableData:0.94,playertableData:1.90,playertableData:1.98,playertableData:0.15,playertableData:1.87,playertableData sortedCell:6.05,============================
Name: D.J. Augustin, Cha PG, SG  DTD
points: 5.88
playertableData:12,playertableData:-0.93,playertableData:0.73,playertableData:2.00,playertableData:0.07,playertableData:3.07,playertableData:0.33,playertableData:-0.66,playertableData:1.26,playertableData sortedCell:5.88,============================
Name: Wesley Matthews, Por SG, SF
points: 5.43
playertableData:13,playertableData:-0.80,playertableData:1.14,playertableData:2.32,playertableData:0.14,playertableData:-0.04,playertableData:1.86,playertableData:-0.39,playertableData:1.21,playertableData sortedCell:5.43,============================
Name: Brandon Knight, Det PG, SG
points: 5.38
playertableData:14,playertableData:-0.31,playertableData:0.46,playertableData:2.10,playertableData:0.30,playertableData:1.17,playertableData:0.84,playertableData:-0.39,playertableData:1.20,playertableData sortedCell:5.38,============================
Name: Paul George, Ind SF, SG
points: 5.37
playertableData:15,playertableData:0.04,playertableData:0.58,playertableData:1.79,playertableData:0.64,playertableData:0.38,playertableData:1.09,playertableData:0.28,playertableData:0.57,playertableData sortedCell:5.37,============================
Name: MarShon Brooks, NJ SG, SF  DTD
points: 5.22
playertableData:16,playertableData:0.67,playertableData:0.34,playertableData:1.26,playertableData:0.53,playertableData:0.03,playertableData:0.97,playertableData:0.01,playertableData:1.41,playertableData sortedCell:5.22,============================
Name: Paul Pierce, Bos SF, SG
points: 5.20
```

Comment: How do you want to access to that ArrayList? Do you want to find player x? or you will simply put them in and later on put them out in the same order?

Comment: Hi Jmolinaso I want to put them in and then out in th esame order,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class `Player` containing variables for name, points etc. Then create an object per player, finally add this to an `ArrayList<Player>`.

```
Player currentPlayer;
ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
// a lot of your code
while (tdIter.hasNext()) {  
    System.out.println("============================");
    Element tdEl = tdIter.next();
    currentPlayer = new Player();
    // instead of that:
    //String name = tdEl.getElementsByClass("playertablePlayerName").text();
    // do that:
    currentPlayer.mName = tdEl.getElementsByClass("playertablePlayerName").text();
    // the same with the rest of the gathered information
    // at the last line in this while loop
    players.add(currentPlayer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Warren!But how can I get them in to the ArrayList<Player>? how can I identify what in the Player Bean will get which data?

Comment: Is it possible that you have no idea about java at all? I mean you managed to get the web site crawled, you managed to get your stuff printed and you tell me that you have no idea how to use an ArrayList or how you create a new class and fill it with some data?

Comment: I know how to use an ArrayList and create a class. However I am struggling adding it to an Object. You are right I am a beginner and I have alot to learn I was hoping maybe someone could help me out. I appriciate your time.

Comment: updated my answer. If you know ArrayList and custom class creation, I still don't get why you have trouble with this...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Warren!

I added a switch in order to go thru all of the elemnts
Hope some people can benifit from my question.Thanks for your time.

```
switch (tdCount++) {

                    case 1:
                        stat1 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        stat2 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        stat3 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        stat4 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        stat5 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        stat6 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        stat7 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        stat8 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        stat9 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        stat10 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                        break;

                    }
                }

                PlayerBean pb = new PlayerBean(name, stat1, stat2, stat3,
                        stat4, stat5, stat6, stat7, stat8, stat9, stat10);
                playerlist.add(pb);
            }
```